# Single event handler instance without static

Tags: c#

I had an event in a usercontrol

```
public event EventHandler EH_OpenDefaultClick;
```

A form when a radio button is click will subscribe to this event. However this form will not be destroyed and whenever the radio button is click, i will subscribe to the event

```
ucStdButton_Recipe.EH_OpenDefaultClick += ucStdButton_Recipe_EH_OpenDefaultClick;
```

with the only line above, every time it will be subscribe, hence triggering multiple time. I can add in the code to compare if it is null. But eventually codes get untidy with all these == null

```
if (ucStdButton_Recipe.EH_OpenDefaultClick == null)
    ucStdButton_Recipe.EH_OpenDefaultClick += ucStdButton_Recipe_EH_OpenDefaultClick;
```

I cannot declare the event as static as the event is subscribe during runtime. Is there any declaration type allowing me to subscribe more easily without the comparison statement

Comment: What your title has to do with the question?

Comment: Why do you need to test for `null` before attaching the event handler delegate?  And why are you only attaching when it is `null`?

Comment: Instead of subscribing every time the radio button is clicked, why not subscribe once and add logic to ignore if the relevant radio button is not selected.

Comment: whats the problem with checking if its null? I would hardly call that clutter

Comment: @Mike if i subscribe it every time, i would have multiple trigger

Comment: @CharlesMager i am just checking if there is any other type of declaration beside static that allows 1 instance during runtime. i believe my c# knowledge is kinda ancient..

Comment: I agree with Charles here, subscribe once instead. Why are you subscribing multiple times? Are you familiar with unsubscribing, i.e. `-=`? Do you dispose your form? Are you opening multiple forms? Where is the radio button located? In some parent form? I'm not sure how static would solve anything. Perhaps you should read a tutorial on how [events work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: If this behaviour is attached to a [RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx), could you use the `Checked` property to either subscribe or unsubscribe depending on the state of the control?

Comment: @MikeofSST i guess the best way for a lazy man for me is to use a bool to subscribe to event only once.

Comment: @ishtarsg It's only 'lazy' if it doesn't work, otherwise it's 'efficient'.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you.

```
    private EventHandler eh_OpenDefaultClick;
    public event EventHandler EH_OpenDefaultClick
    {
        add
        {
            eh_OpenDefaultClick -= value;
            eh_OpenDefaultClick += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            eh_OpenDefaultClick -= value;
        }
    }
```

Removing handler before adding it ensures that there is no more than one instance of the same handler attached at any moment. If you want to have just one handler ever, change `eh_OpenDefaultClick -= value;` to `if (eh_OpenDefaultClick == null)`

Of course you will need to call private `eh_OpenDefaultClick` to raise the event

Comment: this seems prone to bite you in the ass later on. I would rather unsubscribe when I don't want to use the event anymore, not when someone else subscribes to it (even if it's the same method subscribing). I'm not sure OP understand unsubscribing though so IMO you are on the right path. But instead of doing it in the `add` handler, explain that the event can be unsubscribed when needed.